# Error installing unixodbc

Tags: homebrew, php

I am trying to install php55 using brew, but when you start installing the dependency 'unixODBC' stops at the last line

this is the message that shows

```
➜  ~  brew install -vu php55

==> Installing dependencies for php55: unixodbc, homebrew/dupes/zlib
==> Installing php55 dependency: unixodbc
==> Downloading http://www.unixodbc.org/unixODBC-2.3.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/unixodbc-2.3.2.tar.gz
==> Verifying unixodbc-2.3.2.tar.gz checksum
tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/unixodbc-2.3.2.tar.gz
==> ./configure --disable-debug --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2 --enable-gui=no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no

 .......MORE......
 .......MORE......
 .......MORE......
 .......MORE......

 -g -O2 -pthread -c -o _iniScanUntilObject.lo _iniScanUntilObject.c
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -pthread -c _iniPropertyRead.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/_iniPropertyRead.o
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -pthread -c _iniDump.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/_iniDump.o
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I../include -g -O2 -pthread -c _iniScanUntilObject.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/_iniScanUntilObject.o
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link clang  -g -O2 -pthread -no-undefined   -o libinilc.la  iniAllTrim.lo iniAppend.lo iniDelete.lo iniClose.lo iniCommit.lo iniObject.lo iniObjectFirst.lo iniObjectLast.lo iniObjectNext.lo iniObjectSeek.lo iniObjectSeekSure.lo iniObjectUpdate.lo iniObjectInsert.lo iniObjectDelete.lo iniObjectEOL.lo iniOpen.lo iniProperty.lo iniPropertyFirst.lo iniPropertyLast.lo iniPropertyNext.lo iniPropertySeek.lo iniPropertySeekSure.lo iniPropertyUpdate.lo iniPropertyInsert.lo iniPropertyDelete.lo iniPropertyEOL.lo iniPropertyValue.lo iniValue.lo iniToUpper.lo iniElement.lo iniElementCount.lo iniGetBookmark.lo iniGotoBookmark.lo iniCursor.lo _iniObjectRead.lo _iniPropertyRead.lo _iniDump.lo _iniScanUntilObject.lo ../extras/libodbcextraslc.la 

[stops here]
```

Comment: Please consider placing your answer as an answer instead of an edit to the question body...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by updating Xcode to the latest version.